# filter has an error in vanilla javascript small app (to do list)

Tags: javascript, foreach, project

So I'm building a small app using vanilla javascript , this app is a to-do list with some functionality, I have an error when I press on the filter here is the javascript code:

```js
function filterTodo(e) {
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  // console.log(todos);
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
  <div class="select">
    <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="completed">Completed</option>
      <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an image for the error:
[This error keeps showing up when I press on the filter][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63CXI.png

I can't find my mistake but I think that (todo) is not identified in the anonymous function or there is a mistake with the forEach function.
please help and thank you.

Note:Here is the url for the whole app on github:https://github.com/Shtaiwee1/Web_fund_additional_apps/tree/master/To_do_list

Comment: Need to know what `todoList` is and probably how it was actually defined.

Comment: const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

Comment: filterOption.addEventListener("click",filterTodo);       ((this is the event listener for the filter))

Comment: here is the url for the whole code in github:https://github.com/Shtaiwee1/Web_fund_additional_apps/tree/master/To_do_list

Comment: I think I got [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71357675/2813224)

Comment: Thank you this is a great method but I'm wondering why my code isn't working though

Comment: `todoList` might be out of scope or `.children` doesn't translate as a NodeList. If the latter (`console.log(todos)` actually is a NodeList or HTMLCollection) you might have to convert it into an array `[...todos]`. But as I said in my answer iteration isn't needed in this particular case.

Comment: Understood, great explanation sir, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change the class of your list (the `<ul>` not the `<li>`) and let CSS casscading take care of the rest. `.forEach()` is definitely not needed nor any array or NodeList for that matter. Also, you should always have a `default` in a `switch()` -- in this example `default` removes both classes from `<ul>` (it doesn't matter if class is actually there or not so covering both is 100% no calculations involved). BTW, "click" is ok in this situation, but you should use ["change" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) since it's designed for form controls like `<select>`.

```js
const form = document.forms[0];

const select = form.elements.filter;

select.addEventListener('change', filterList);

function filterList(e) {
  const select = e.target;
  const list = document.querySelector('.list');

  if (select.matches('#filter')) {
    switch (select.value) {
      case 'done':
        list.classList.remove('open');
        list.classList.add('done');
        break;
      case 'open':
        list.classList.remove('done');
        list.classList.add('open');
        break;
      default:
        list.classList.remove('done');
        list.classList.remove('open');
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
li.open::before {
  content: '⬛'
}

li.done::before {
  content: '☑️'
}

.list.open li.done {
  display: none
}

.list.done li.open {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id='filter'>
    <option default value=''>All</option>
    <option value='done'>Completed</option>
    <option value='open'>Uncompleted</option>
  </select>
  <ul class='list'>
    <li class='done'>Task</li>
    <li class='open'>Task</li>
    <li class='done'>Task</li>
    <li class='done'>Task</li>
    <li class='open'>Task</li>
    <li class='done'>Task</li>
    <li class='open'>Task</li>
    <li class='open'>Task</li>
    <li class='done'>Task</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show/hide your list of "todo" you can simplify this by using data attributes and then toggle them.  Here I used one for the "action" state and the other to show/hide based on that.

```js
function filterTodo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
  let todoSelect = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");
  const todos = todoList.querySelectorAll(".todo-item");
  let val = event.target.value;
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    todo.dataset.status = todo.dataset.action === val && val !== "all" ? val : val === "all" ? "" : "none";
  });
}
let b = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
b.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);
let sel = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");
sel.addEventListener('change', filterTodo);
```

```css
.todo-container,
.todo-container .todo-list {
  border: solid 1px lime;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.todo-item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #40404010;
  border: 1px solid #40404040;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.todo-item[data-status="completed"] {
  background-color: #10401010;
}

.todo-item[data-action="completed"]::before {
  content: "DONE: ";
  color: green;
}

.todo-item[data-status="completed"] span {
  color: lime;
}

.todo-item[data-status="uncompleted"] {
  background-color: #40101010;
  text-decoration-line: underline overline;
}

.todo-item[data-status="none"] {
  display: none;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}

.todo-item[data-status=""] {
  text-decoration-color: cyan;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input" />
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
     <i class="fas fa-plus-square">[+]</i>
  </button>
  <div class="select-container">
    <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="completed">Completed</option>
      <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li class="todo-item">Get a new cat: I have no status or action</li>
    <li class="todo-item" data-action="completed" data-status="completed">Get a new Hippo</li>
    <li class="todo-item" data-action="uncompleted" data-status="uncompleted">Send MORE money!</li>
    <li class="todo-item" data-status="none">Send me money! I was hidden?</li>
    <li class="todo-item" data-status="fish">Send me money! fish?</li>
    <li class="todo-item" data-status="">Get to the bank NOW!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice approach, thank you for the ideas